# Golang parsing date in RFC822Z format without leading zero

Tags: date, go, date-parsing

I have a date string I can't control that I'm trying to parse into a Date.

The format most closely resembles RFC822Z.

RFC822Z = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700"

Reference: https://yourbasic.org/golang/format-parse-string-time-date-example/

However, it does not have the leading zero.

Example: "5 Dec 2022 20:15:21 +0000"

The way I saw in other posts, is to write a manual format.

```
parseTime, timeParseError = time.Parse("2 Jan 2006 15:04:21 -0700", stringDate)
```

However, when I try that, I get a warning:

```
parsing time "2 Jan 2006 15:04:21 -0700" as "2 Jan 2006 15:04:21 -0700": cannot parse " -0700" as "1" (SA1002)
```

Running it despite the warning fails to part, unsurprisingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time format doesn't match - in your example you have "5 Dec 2022", but you are using "2 Jan 06", and in your reference format you hvae "15:04:21" but it should be "15:04:05".

Your reference format should be `2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700` not `2 Jan 06 15:04:21 -0700`

https://go.dev/play/p/Shc381WgB6_7